# Set the units of slider property to m instead of mm python

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, panel

I'm using the location property as shown below but wonder how I can control the units when dragging the slider? Currently when I drag it, it moves in mm as this is my scene unit, is it possible to set the unit regardless the scene unit? so it can be in meters instead of mm.

```
ob = bpy.data.objects['Rock']    
row = layout.row()
row.column().prop(ob, "location")
```

This is what appears:

[image]

Comment: This is something I'm also interested in. Any answers how to set individual units for sliders? Thank you.